# Como pegar o usuário corrente na Pagina HTML para inserir no banco Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Olá estou precisando pegar o usuário que esta logado no sistema para quando ele fizer um insert ou Update no banco de dados inserir o registro dele, atualmente no template eu já consigo pegar o nome do usuário  com este comando

```
 {{ current_user.name }}
```

Porem quando o usuário chamar uma rota gostaria de pegar este usuário para inserir no registro das manipulações do banco, hoje estou usando o python e o Flask na minha aplicação, poderiam me dar uma ajuda ?

Abaixo o codigo da View onde consigo pegar o usuario corrente, mas preciso dos dados dele quando chamar a proxima rota

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block conteudo %}

{% include 'components/notification.html' %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <span><p>Olá <label  name="usuario">{{ current_user.name }}</label>, escolha o arquivo com as informações para começarmos </p></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
              <form action = "/uploader" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
              <input type = "file" name = "file" />
              <input type = "submit"/>
              </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Rodrigo, por favor coloque o código que você esta tentando usar na `view/controller`

Comment: Olá, acabei de atualizar o meu post, o que eu queria e pegar o usuario corrente e tentar passar esta informação para a Rota /uploader , cheguei a colocar o {{current_user.name}} como parametro mas não funciona, na View ele funciona ok , pega os dados do usuario que esta logado no momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `flask-login` trabalha com o *current_user* em escopo global na aplicação, da mesma forma que vc usa o current_user no template, vc pode usá-lo na sua rota *'/uploader'*, basta vc importar o *current_user* do próprio `flask-login`, veja o exemplo abaixo, levando em consideração que o usuário esteja logado:

```
from flask_login import current_user

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def uploader():
    print(current_user.nome)
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo aqui, gostaria de aproveitar e pedir uma indicação de curso ou documentação para aprimorar meus conhecimentos na utilização dos recursos do flask e saber se para python web esta seria a melhor opção.